# Can we use long wires with ultrasonic module HC-SR04

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, wire, ultrasound, timing-analysis

I want to use Ultrasonic module [HC-SR04](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Proximity/HCSR04.pdf) as ranging sensor but my MCU board is approx 80 ft away from the place where I have to put the US module.

These are its pin-outs and descriptions:

[image: HC-SR04 Module back and front]

[image: Pin out descriptions]

[image: Timing diagram]

My ranging is from 1 ft (min) to 6 ft (max) and accuracy is +-1 inch (2-3 cm).

Is it possible to run the 4 wires (Vcc, Trig, Echo, Gnd) directly from my MCU board to the US module 80 ft away?

Comment: Of course it is possible to use long wires, but it is quite likely it will not work as intended. If it works depends among other things on the (resistive, capacitive and inductive) specs of the cable and the driving capability of the Ultrasonic module and MCU board, etc

Comment: How it the distance being determined? Difference in time between start of the trigger signal to the end of echo signal? With long cables, you defenitely won't see these infinite rising and falling edges from the Timing Diagram picture anymore: where does the trigger signal start and where does the echo signal end?

Comment: If this MCU board is not expensive, I would buy a second and place it close to the Ultrasonic module and do the communication between the MCU's using a robust communication protocol.

Comment: If I use RS232 drivers at both ends at the MCU and US module will that make my signal edges sharp? Unfortunately I cannot put a second MCU in the design.. I have to work out a way without that.

Comment: I can't tell, I've hardly no experience with (low-level) RS232

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More cable == more inductance and capacitance == more phase delay

Common way to design for long cables

1. Twisted wire
2. use a signal driver
3. Shielded cable

Comment: Twisting which cables?

Comment: If I use CAT5 ethernet cable which has twisted pairs will that work?

Comment: you should first try with CAT5 ethernet cable and see result if you are not getting good result than you need to connect some kind of signal booster or amplifier

Comment: @Huisman Twisting wire will help in reduce noise

Comment: @JayVadoliya In *general* twisting cables can help reduce radiation and the susceptibility to EMI. But it will increase slew rate ass well, so, *in this case*, twisting cables might worsen it as well.

Comment: @Huisman so if I use RS232 line drivers at both ends will that work?

Comment: RS485 would be better.

Comment: @scorpdaddy Don't you need more than just a driver? I've little experience, but who controls the start and stop bits and handshaking etc at *both* end?

Comment: You don't have to use RS485 for serial comms any more than you do with RS232.  There doesn't have to be any start,stop bits at all.